# adding click listener to titlebar image

Tags: android, android-activity, titlebar

Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays everyone!

I'm trying to setup a listener on the image icon that appears on the left side of the default title bar, but so far not having any luck.

Here's my Activity's onCreate:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   findViewById(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override public void onClick(View v) {
           System.out.println("It works!");
       }
   });
}
```

Any suggestions?  I'm hoping to not see the answer "it's not possible" :)

Comment: Why don't you use an ActionBar?

Comment: Are you talking about [this titlebar](http://sree.cc/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/image1.jpg)? If so, you should look into implementing an ActionBar, the title bar is now pretty much deprecated as a UI idiom.

Comment: Yes, I think you would use the ActionBar and implement the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method of your activity. I believe the id of the app icon on the ActionBar is `android.R.id.home`

Comment: @RaghavSood because I'm not looking to do a full customization.  I'm already satisfied with the default appearance, so I felt it'd be easier to just add a click listener than try to reinvent the wheel, know what I mean?

Comment: @dmon I'm actually trying to emulate something like this: http://i.haymarket.net.au/News/best-samsung-galaxy-S3-apps-spotify.jpg where the top left icon is clickable. Was this achieved via ActionBar? If so, how would I go about doing something like that? Create my custom view and override the default title bar with it? If so, what's the height that apps tend to use?

Comment: Yeah, that's an action bar, or something close to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an id for the left icon, however for the classic title bar, there is an id available: `android.R.id.title` Here is a sample Activity using this id. The `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);` should force the classic title bar regardless of theme.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    View v = findViewById (android.R.id.title);
    v.setClickable(true);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Basically, what this does, is it finds the id of the title bar (`android.R.id.title`) then assigns an `onClickListener` to it.

This will **not** work with `ActionBar`s, only classic window title bars.

Comment: Did you actually try running this on a phone? I'm getting a null pointer with my Galaxy S3.

Comment: Yes, on 4.0.4. You need to have a classic theme, such as Theme.Black/Theme.Light. The new Holo themes use the ActionBar, which like other people mentioned use a different implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ActionBar. Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to have it also for Android versions less than 3.0. To make the Icon clickable, see the ActionBar API Docs (see link below). It's very easy, you just activate the behaviour and then it works like a menu-item with a special item-id.

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home