# Android: Title bar onclick launcher icon

Tags: android, icons, onclicklistener, titlebar

I'd like to add an onclick listener to my launcer icon in the title bar of my app.
Since i'm also supporting API level 8 i do not have an Action bar.

The following code works great, however the menu is set back to default (white background, white text, small icon etc.)

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    View v = findViewById (android.R.id.title);
    v.setClickable(true);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

source: [adding click listener to titlebar image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033204/adding-click-listener-to-titlebar-image)

How can I keep my standard layout of my title bar (black background color, white text and large icon), while also implement this onclick listener?

Here are two shots of the different layouts:
good: http://gyazo.com/40d1cdd5302de3cd28b698b68164a556 
bad: http://gyazo.com/3cee42524ec4167392baec6cc2369584

(Note that the good one is also has a greater height)

Comment: Just read about ActionBarSherlock here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14033897/1444854